# Program that counts even digits in given number, but eats the first digit, and sometimes not. How to fix?

Tags: php, html, css

So basically, everything works except that the program eats the first digit sometimes, and sometimes does not. Examples:

**1. Example**

- INPUT: 221
- *EXPECTED OUTPUT: 2*
- ACTUAL OUTPUT: 1

**2. Example**

- INPUT: 122
- *EXPECTED OUTPUT: 2*
- ACTUAL OUTPUT: 2

**3. Example**

- INPUT: 422
- *EXPECTED OUTPUT: 3*
- ACTUAL OUTPUT: 3

Example 2 works because the program eats the first digit, which is not an even digit, so the count works either way. Whereas for Example 1, the program eats one of the **2**s and thus, the program outputs **1**, and not **2**, since one of them is gone and the count didn't get it. And in the third example, it suddenly works. I am sure it has something to do with the math, but I just do not get it.

**index.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 13px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="result.php">
            <center>
            <label for="Input">Въведете число:</label>
            <input type="number" id="Input" name="Input"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Провери!">
            </center>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**result.php**

```
<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <body>
        <?php
            $input = $_REQUEST["Input"];
            $count = 0;
            for ($i = 0; $i < $input; $i++)
            {
                $x = $input % 10;
                if ($x % 2 == 0)
                {
                    $count++;
                }
                $input = (int)($input / 10);
            }
        ?>
        Числото <?php echo $_POST["Input"]; ?> съдържа <?php echo $count ?> четни цифри.
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just count the even numbers in the string rather than iterating? What is `0` in your example, even?

Comment: (Alternative method: https://3v4l.org/kLZDS)

Comment: Aleksandar Haralanov you can check my answer for an easy solution

Comment: better solution with for loop: https://3v4l.org/0Zvqu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**result.php**

```
<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <body>
        <?php
            $input = $_REQUEST["Input"];
            $count = 0;
            for ($i = 0; $i < $input; $i++)
            {
                $x = $input % 10;
                if ($x % 2 == 0)
                {
                    $count++;
                }
                $input = (int)($input / 10);
            }
        ?>
        Числото <?php echo $_POST["Input"]; ?> съдържа <?php echo $count ?> четни цифри.
    </body>
</html>
```

Change to:

```
<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <body>
        <?php
            $input = str_split($_REQUEST["Input"]);
            $input_length = count($input);
            $count = 0;

            for($i = 0; $i < $input_length; ++$i){
                if($input[$i] % 2 === 0){
                    ++$count;
                }
            }
        ?>
        Числото <?php echo $_POST["Input"]; ?> съдържа <?php echo $count ?> четни цифри.
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is that this program is for an exam. They require that we use a FOR loop. But either way, thank you for your help.

Comment: Feels a bit scummy to ask for help like this for an official exam, but fair enough give me a second.

Comment: Yeah, it is pretty pathetic, I tried to fix it as much as my abilities allowed me to, but I couldn't. So I resorted to help on here.

Comment: Will the edit work? It now uses a for loop.

Comment: Yes, it is working now, thank you very much!

Comment: There I moved the count out of the loop, if there is a better way to calculate an array length in PHP I would be happy to further improve it.

Comment: (Nope, that's the right way)